# Plotting in matlab time in secs as HH:MM:SS.FFF

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 356*2 array lets call him tmp
When the (:,1) is in milisecs

Now i am looking to make a plot of X over y when i want the X be showed in HH:MM:SS.FFF secs

I have converted the secs to that format by

```
datestr(tmp(:,1)*0.001/24/3600,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```

But this is a string, how can i use it in my plot function

Answer (score 2):

You can apply what are called date format strings to the axes of plots with built-in function datetick. For example, with your first column being time, you could call

> > plot(tmp(:, 1), tmp(:, 2))

to plot the data. Then call:

> > datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF')

to format the values assigned to ticks on the x-axis based on the second input argument. NOTE that, in order to perform this conversion, the function assumes that the time data is in units of DAYS, so if your data is in milliseconds, you should divide your time data by (24*60*60*1000). Note also that when you zoom on this graph, the new labels will not be re-written at each scale as numeric ones would have been. To get around this, I thoroughly recommend datetickzoom from the MATLAB file exchange.

Answer (score -1):

Use your original value of tmp(:,1) for the plot function and then use your `datestr(tmp(:,1)*0.001/24/3600,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')` as the label?

Comment: Welcome to SO. please don't post comments as answers. Your post seems to be pointing in the right direction (using labels). Can you please extend it into a complete answer? Until then, I must downvote it.

Comment: That was intended to be an answer not a comment. I will edit it to be more of an answer form but there is not much more to include in it